# Can't import LDAP query feed data

Tags: drupal, ldap, ldap-query, drupal-feeds

I've set up an LDAP query that successfully pulls all data from the field `physicaldeliveryofficename` from our Windows Active Directory:

[image: LDAP_query.png]

I also setup a View that uses the query to further refine the list, so I am confident that the query itself is working:

[image: LDAP_views.png]

The problem occurs when I try to use Feeds Importers to grab that data and add it to my Offices content type.  Here are my settings:

**Basic settings**

Name: Offices
Attach to content type: Use standalone form
Periodic import: 1 day
Import on submission: checked

**Fecher**

LDAP Query Fetcher is selected

**LDAP Query Fetcher**

LDAP Query: HPSI Offices (that's the right query)

**Parser**

LDAP Entry Parser for Feeds is selected

**Processor**

Node processor is selected

**Node processor**

Bundle: Office
Language: Language neutral
Insert new nodes: Insert new nodes
Update existing nodes: Update existing nodes
Text format: plain text (also tried HTML)
Action to take when previously imported nodes are missing in the feed: Delete non-existent nodes
Author: Currently using user 1, but also tried anonymous
Authorize: checked
Expire nodes: never

**Mapping**

Source: [physicaldeliveryofficename]
Target: Title (title)
Used as unique

When I run this feed importer, the only thing that happens is a single Office is created with a blank title (see last image.)  Can anyone tell me why this importer isn't working when both the LDAP query and a View that depends on it are working?

[image: Feeds_import.png]

UPDATE: I opened an issue against LDAP Feeds at Drupal.org and it appears I'm not the only one with this problem. https://www.drupal.org/node/2685009

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a great deal like the [issue reported on the LDAP module's issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1911762). Try applying the patch from comment 11.

Comment: Unfortunately that appears to have to do with parsing an array of multiple fields.  I applied the patch and the problem persists.